# angular cli app with socket.io on IIS

Tags: sockets, iis, socket.io, angular-cli

I made a small simple chat-app, using angular and also socket.io. Now i want to deploy it on IIS 7. The angular-app works fine, but socket.io can't be found...

"zone.js:2935 GET http://localhost:4200/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M5x4rhh 404 (Not Found)"

When running the server-dir (socket.io) via **npm start**, theres no problem.
But as far it runs on IIS it cant be found. 
I'm really desperate 'cause I've no plan what I'm doing wrong.

**IIS**
Sites
--chatapp <--angular-app (dist-dir)
----server (socket-io)

Hope you may have some adivices :)